# Why no warning when uint32 casts to uint8 with gcc C

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, gcc-warning

Compiling with -Wconversion,

```
uint32_val = 0x00000C00;
uint_8_val = ((uint32_val >> 8) & 0x000000FF);
```

gives no warning.

What compiler flag shall I use to get a warning?

Comment: Why it happens, I believe `-Wconversion` will *not* warn when the conversion will *not* result in a value change (which it won't in your case due to the and-mask). From the gcc docs for `-Wconversion` "Does not warn... or if the value is not changed by the conversion.." Which flag to use? Dunno, I use clang. sry.

Comment: This code should not give warning, but I understand what you want. have you tried this? `uint_8_val = ((uint32_val >> 8) & 0x1FF);` If it gives warning you are fine, I quess. But my bet goes for you get an error for this. :-)

Comment: Yes, the compiler seems to be smart and evaluates/calculates the expression, and if the end result fits the variable to the left everything is fine. I would still like to have a warning =), but that is more my problem to adapt too it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no warning because the *expression*:

```
((uint32_val >> 8) & 0x000000FF)
```

is always convertible to a type that fits in a byte. Your *uint32_val* is not cast, but takes part in a calculation. The compiler can optimize this, and in this case it is clear the result after bit-wise and-ing with `000000ff` will always fit the provided *l-value* type, hence no warning.

Comment: Yepp, seems that I am too "typed" of a programmer. But as you and others have explained the compiler seems to optimize as much as possible to fit the variable to the left. If it is unsuccessful it gives a warning (with wconversion).

Answer (score 2):

Your code will compile fine. The type of plain constants is determined to be the best fitting.

You will get warning for this code:

```
uint32_val = 0x00000C00;
uint_8_val = ((uint32_val >> 8) & 0x000001FF);
```

Compilers shouldn't enforce coding guidelines. That's two different thing.

Comment: Since the result of this operation is no longer suitable for a byte-sized l-value, the compiler will be forced to implement an implicit conversion and will warn about it.